# PHP foreach invalid argument supplied

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying display error messages on a form but only one is displayed (the last one always). I tried using a foreach loop but I keep getting the invalid argument error. The following displays errors one by one. Code is inside a class...

```
public $errorContainer = '';

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// ERROR MESSAGE PROCESSING
// ------------------------------------------------------------
private function responseMessage($respBool, $respMessage) {
    $return['error'] = $respBool;
    $return['msg'] = $respMessage;
    if (isset($_POST['plAjax']) && $_POST['plAjax'] == true) {
        echo json_encode($return);
    } else {
        $this->errorContainer = $respMessage;
    }
}
```

The following always gives me the invalid for each argument error.

```
private function responseMessage($respBool, $respMessage) {
    $return['error'] = $respBool;
    $return['msg'] = $respMessage;
    if (isset($_POST['plAjax']) && $_POST['plAjax'] == true) {
        echo json_encode($return);
    } else {
        foreach ($respMessage as $value) {
            $this->errorContainer = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This function is not called - the $errorContainer is. Sorry it should show private instead of public. I mean the function called only within the class. $this->responseMessage(true, $msg);

Comment: `var_dump($respMessage)`

Comment: try `var_dump($respMessage);` on the first line of `responseMessage()`, and give us the result please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your `foreach()` with this:

```
private function responseMessage($respBool, $respMessage) {
  // ...code...
  foreach ((array) $respMessage as $value) {
    $this->errorContainer .= $value;
  }
  // ...code---
}
```

Using type casting `(array)` above will make it works for both array and string type.

**Edit:**

Use this solution (type casting) only in your last effort. But your real problem is you're not passing an array to the function. See this code:

```
// incorrect
$msg = 'This is a message';
$this->responseMessage($some_bool, $msg);

// correct
$msg = array('This is a message');
$this->responseMessage($some_bool, $msg);

// correct
$msg = array('This is a message', 'And another message');
$this->responseMessage($some_bool, $msg);
```

If you pass the argument correctly like above, you don't need to cast `$respMessage` to array.

Comment: But I still get the Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error.

Comment: It looks like the `$respMessage` you passed to the function is not an array. You can cast `$respMessage` to array like my edited code.

Comment: I agree on the concat, but this cast isn't really a solution. The problem is in amont.

Comment: I agree, a cast is more of a hack than a proper solution.

Comment: @nickb Why is it not a good solution? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Here your coding like "hey sweety little var, you're not an array, but I need you to be an array to execute the next line, to BE AN ARRAY AN SHUT UP !". You better should try to understand why this var isn't an array ;)

Comment: Generally, you should never use a cast if you don't really know why to do it.

Comment: @samsamX $respMessage is not a property, it is only a method argument. How can I make that an array?

Comment: The question isn't "How to make that an array ?", but "Why am I sending a not-array var to this function ?"

Comment: @samsamX I'm sorry but I have no idea what you are talking about. Would you care to answer or you just want to troll?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to explain you that use a cast is just like hide your real problem : you are sending a non-array var to a function which need an array one. Just think about it, and look in amont, where you're calling the function.